# Kubernetes CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I got error when creating deployment.
This is my Dockerfile that i have run and test it on local, i also push it to DockerHub

```
FROM node:14.15.4
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "server.js" ]
```

In my raspberry pi 3 model B, i have install k3s using `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`
Here is my controller-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: controller-deployment
  labels:
    app: controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        image: akirayorunoe/node-controller-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
```

After run this file the pod is error

When i log the pod, it said

```
standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Here is the reponse from describe pod

```
Name:         controller-deployment-8669c9c864-sw8kh
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         raspberrypi/192.168.0.30
Start Time:   Fri, 21 May 2021 11:21:05 +0700
Labels:       app=controller
              pod-template-hash=8669c9c864
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.0.43
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.0.43
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/controller-deployment-8669c9c864
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:   containerd://439edcfdbf49df998e3cabe2c82206b24819a9ae13500b0                                                                                        13b9bac1df6e56231
    Image:          akirayorunoe/node-controller-server
    Image ID:       docker.io/akirayorunoe/node-controller-server@sha256:e1c5115                                                                                        2f9d596856952d590b1ef9a486e136661076a9d259a9259d4df314226
    Port:           3001/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 21 May 2021 11:24:29 +0700
      Finished:     Fri, 21 May 2021 11:24:29 +0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-txm85 (ro                                                                                        )
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-txm85:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-txm85
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m33s                  default-scheduler  Successfully ass                                                                                        igned default/controller-deployment-8669c9c864-sw8kh to raspberrypi
  Normal   Pulled     5m29s                  kubelet            Successfully pul                                                                                        led image "akirayorunoe/node-controller-server" in 3.072053213s
  Normal   Pulled     5m24s                  kubelet            Successfully pul                                                                                        led image "akirayorunoe/node-controller-server" in 3.018192177s
  Normal   Pulled     5m6s                   kubelet            Successfully pul                                                                                        led image "akirayorunoe/node-controller-server" in 3.015959209s
  Normal   Pulled     4m34s                  kubelet            Successfully pul                                                                                        led image "akirayorunoe/node-controller-server" in 2.921116157s
  Normal   Created    4m34s (x4 over 5m29s)  kubelet            Created containe                                                                                        r controller
  Normal   Started    4m33s (x4 over 5m28s)  kubelet            Started containe                                                                                        r controller
  Normal   Pulling    3m40s (x5 over 5m32s)  kubelet            Pulling image "a                                                                                        kirayorunoe/node-controller-server"
  Warning  BackOff    30s (x23 over 5m22s)   kubelet            Back-off restart                                                                                        ing failed container
```

Here is the [error images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Nwv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to launch a container built for x86 (or x86_64, same difference) on an ARM machine. This does not work. Containers for ARM must be built specifically for ARM and contain ARM executables. While major projects are slowly adding ARM support to their builds, most random images you find on Docker Hub or whatever will not work on ARM.

Comment: thanks, i have fix it by creating multi-arch images